# Live search in table for specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to create a live search for a specific column in a table. I've searched a bit but I can only find solutions to search over all columns. This is my code:

```js
function searchInTable(table) {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    jQuery(table).each(function (index) {
        if (!index) return;
        jQuery(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search-table-input" class="search-table-input" type="text"
           onkeyup="searchInTable('.table tr')" placeholder="Search Number...">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="table-number">
        <span class="nobr">Number</span>
      </th>
   <th class="table-date">
        <span class="nobr">Date</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>264</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2019-01-02</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>967</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2019-01-02</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>385</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2019-01-02</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>642</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2019-01-02</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My function has some errors and don't work like it should.

How can I change my function that way that when I start typing only the number gets filtered? I need to make the function dynamically so that I can pass the column which should be used for the search.

Answer (score 2):

The line that's causing it to search over all the columns is this one:

```
jQuery(this).find("td").each(function () {
```

...which takes each cell in the current row and looks to see if it contains `value`. If you only want to check as specific column, you should pass in the column index as something like `columnIndex`, and then you can select the correct column by doing `jQuery(this).find("td").eq(columnIndex)`, using jQuery's `.eq()` function to select the correct one. The code should look something like this:

```
function searchInTableColumn(table, columnIndex) {

    //check this.value exists to avoid errors
    var value = this.value ? this.value.toLowerCase().trim() : "";

    jQuery(table).each(function (index) {
        if (!index) return;
        var tableCell = jQuery(this).find("td").eq(columnIndex);
        var id = tableCell.text().toLowerCase().trim();
        var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
        $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
    });
}
```

Then you can call `searchInTableColumn(table, 0)` and it will only look in the first column.

Comment: Cool, thank you for your help! But when I execute it and start typing in the input, I get this issue in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: I've changed the first line to var value = this.value but now when I start typing every disappears and the search is not working (seems so). So maybe can you test and edit your answer?

Comment: I based my answer on your code, I didn't change that part of it. If it was working before, it should we working now. I can try and guess a fix, I suppose!